# Safely save data to django model using AJAX

Tags: ajax, django

I have a model say `TestModel` as follows:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    description = models.TextField()
```

Now I can use a `ModelForm` to save data to this model. However, say I want to use Ajax and send a url as follows `savethis?name=ABC&desc=SomeRandomDescription` to a view that handles it as follows:

```
def savethis(request):
    if request.GET['name'] and request.GET['desc']:
        name = request.GET['name']
        desc = request.GET['desc']
        test = TestModel(name=name, description=desc)
        test.save
        return HttpResponse('Ok')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Fail')
```

What's to stop someone from running a script that can easily hit this url with valid data and thus save data to my model? How do I ensure that incoming data is sent only from the right source?

One option is sending the data as JSON in a Post request but even that's not too hard to emualte.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you have stumbled upon the great security flaw that is [Cross-site Scripting attacks.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) They are several ways you can get around it, but going into all of them in one answer would be fruitless. I suggest you Google the term and do some poking around, and you will find several different methods on how to protect your site better.

Django has a [security page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/#cross-site-scripting-xss-protection) dedicated to talking about how to protect your site.

Comment: Googled the term. Nothing specific to my requirements, of course but it says something about `SQL injection protection` which is similar to what I need. I'm wondering how to implement this in this scenario

Comment: I've updated the answer with a link back to Django's documentation.